# Radio button value is not transferred to model - ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, radio-button

I have a web page in asp .net core with the following inputs:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.UserScoreModel 
        <div>
            <label asp-for="GivenServiceScore"></label><br />
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" name="servScore" id="servScore" value="5" /> 5
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" id="servScore" name="servScore" value="4" /> 4
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" id="servScore" name="servScore" value="3" /> 3
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" id="servScore" name="servScore" value="2" /> 2
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" id="servScore" name="servScore" value="1" /> 1
            <span asp-validation-for="GivenServiceScore" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <h5 style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px">@ViewBag.CongratsMessage</h5>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="GivenCommentary"></label><br />
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="GivenCommentary"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="GivenCommentary" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit score</button>
        </div>
```

A user is supposed to give a rating and leave a commentary. **My problem is** that a value from checked radio button doesn't get transferred to a model. When I set a breakpoint and look at the parameter `GivenServiceScore` it is always `0`. It seems like a minor issue, but I can't understand what am I missing. 
Here is the model:

```
public class UserScoreModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Please give a rating")]
        public int GivenServiceScore { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Please leave a commentary")]
        public String GivenCommentary { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserReview(UserScoreModel score)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserReviews review = new UserReviews()
                {
                    GivenServiceScore = score.GivenServiceScore,
                    GivenCommentary = score.GivenCommentary,
                };

                _db.UserReviews.Add(review);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                ViewBag.CongratsMessage = "Thank you for participating!";
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add id and name after using asp-for tag, it will be automatically generated, like this:

[image]

View:

```
@model WebApplication174.Models.UserScoreModel
    <form method="post" asp-action="GivenServiceScore">
        <div>
            <label asp-for="GivenServiceScore"></label><br />
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" value="5" /> 5
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" value="4" /> 4
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" value="3" /> 3
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" value="2" /> 2
            <input required asp-for="GivenServiceScore" type="radio" style="padding-left:15px" value="1" /> 1
            <span asp-validation-for="GivenServiceScore" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <h5 style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px">@ViewBag.CongratsMessage</h5>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="GivenCommentary"></label><br />
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="GivenCommentary"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="GivenCommentary" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit score</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GivenServiceScore(UserScoreModel score)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserReviews review = new UserReviews()
                {
                    GivenServiceScore = score.GivenServiceScore,
                    GivenCommentary = score.GivenCommentary,
                };

                ViewBag.CongratsMessage = "Thank you for participating!";
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Result：

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I deleted my custom `name` and `id` fields, now it works!